# Tunneling/ Port forwarding to two IPs

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, tunneling

I am trying to run an application locally that uses a database, webservices etc in another network so I am trying to tunnel through a computer with access. However web services are used over two (possibly more) ips and I can't map one port to multiple ips or is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you reconfigure the web services client to access one of the services on another port? For example, if you open an ssh tunnel using something like:

```
ssh -L8080:ws1host:8080 -L8081:ws2host:8080 user@remotehost
```

Then you can access the remote ws1host:8080 on 127.0.0.1:8080 and the remote ws2host:8080 on 127.0.0.1:8081